# Expectation value of $\mathrm{SU(1, 1)}$ parity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, symmetry, quantum-spin

The $\mathrm{su(1, 1)}$ Lie algebra is spanned by the generators $K_+$, $K_−$ and $K_0$, which satisfy the commutation relations:

$$[K_0, K_{±}] = ±K_{±}, [K_−, K_+] = 2K_0.$$

We can define the displacement operator as:
$$D(ξ) = \exp(ξK_+ − ξ^∗K_−).$$

Above operator acts on a fixed or reference state $|k,0>$ to give:
$$|ξ> = D(ξ)|k, 0>.$$
Can anybody please tell me what is expectation value of parity operator $(-1)^{K_0}$ or how to drive it?

Comment: Have you computed $\langle \xi|K_0|\xi\rangle$?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, for the lowest normalized state we have $K_0|k, 0>= k|k, 0>$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, the quantity $⟨ξ|K_0|ξ⟩=k\frac{1+|ξ|^2}{1-|ξ|^2}$.